# Split xls file into small xls files

Tags: filesystems, perl, tcsh

I want to split the `sample.xlsx` (containing 3 sheets) file into the 3 different 
`sheet1.xlsx sheet2.xlsx sheet3.xlsx` files ,
I have  [John McNamara](https://github.com/jmcnamara) Perl package repositories VERSION = 2.37.

I am adding sample code of parsing Excel file

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# Xls Parser : command : perl 
BEGIN {
    push (@INC,"/usr/local/buildpkgs/latest/perl");
}
use lib "/usr/local/buildpkgs/latest/perl/lib/site_perl/5.8.8";
use lib "/depot/perl-5.8.9/lib/site_perl/5.8.9";
use lib "/usr/local/buildpkgs/rev9/perl/ExcelWriter/lib/site_perl/5.8.3";

use Excel::Writer::XLSX;
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;
use Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX;
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel::Utility;
```

PS:The `sample.xlsx` is not a CSV file.

Comment: you want GUI base workaround or command based ?

Comment: Command based. 
I want to define a script to do it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a program to parse excel files and is not a *nix question.

Comment: I have edited the question. Does it still look off-topic ? @terdon

Comment: Yup. Your question asks for a full blown perl program to do a task that has nothing to do with *nix. While simple perl scripting questions are on topic, those are more about manipulating text files, the sort of thing that *nix sysadmins need to do daily. Asking for help on using a specific Perl module to manipulate excel files is not on topic. In any case, asking for someone to write the entire script for you is never on topic. If you edit the question to show your attempt at this and explain which particular part of it is causing you problems, then it might be on topic on [so], but not here.

Answer (score 1):

You can run this code,

```
Sub SaveSheets()
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    strPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        ws.Copy
        'Use this line if you want to break any links:
        BreakLinks Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)
        Workbooks(Workbooks.Count).Close True, strPath & ws.Name & ".xlsx"
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub BreakLinks(wb As Workbook)
    Dim lnk As Variant
    For Each lnk In wb.LinkSources(xlExcelLinks)
        wb.BreakLink lnk, xlLinkTypeExcelLinks
    Next
End Sub
```

To run the code, do the following:

1. Open the VBA editor (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>)
2. In the tree in the top left corner,  right click on your workbook and insert a new module
3. Copy the above code into this module
4. Close the VBA editor
5. In Excel press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> to run macros and select `SaveSheets`

For more help on [adding VBA](https://superuser.com/questions/801609/how-do-i-add-vba-in-ms-office).

Comment: And how do you do his on a *nix machine that doesn't have MS Office?

Comment: @terdon OP can install wine

Comment: Yes, but this is really not on topic here. Both because it's a ure programming question and because it's an MS-only question and because your answer is an MS-only language answer.

Comment: @terdon that's right, it's off-topic

Comment: I undeleted this. We may as well leave it until the system deletes it, it might be useful for someone.

Comment: @terdon ok, I don't mind